# How can I download only part of a page?

Tags: c#

I have 100 pages on my site, but I want download only part a page instead of all page content.

I want just one box of each page to download, the file size is 10 KB.
For this I Use WebClient and htmlagilitypack .

```
 WebClient Client = new WebClient();
 var result = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(Client.DownloadData(URL));
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted this because it's a decent question.

Comment: How is your website structured and how is it served? For instance if you have a CMS that opens one set of options, and if you have a server side language you can use you could set up a separate URL with appropriate code to extract the desired location for a given resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible, because HTTP is not designed to deliver *a specific part* of a web page. It does support [range requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35), but for that you would need to know where exactly (in terms of bytes) the desired content is located.

You can

- download the whole page and then
- use a HTML parsing library to extract the part you need.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this could be done via PHP's GET requests; send a request appended to the URL and it only displays the content they want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this.

The **only solution** is changing the website structure itself. if you have control of the server -

Change the architecture of your website, making the data in the box accessible via an **ajax** call. 
Now you can get the data via the WebClient.
If that data is already served via a API call, you can point your WebClient to that URI Instead.

Here is an example of structuring you website based on ajax -
[AJAX with jQuery and ASP.NET](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this could be done via PHP's GET requests; send a request appended to the URL and it only displays the content they want.

Comment: I assume the OP is using the Microsoft TechStack. So I based my example on it.