# Is it possible to download only the HEAD tag of a page?

Tags: java, http, web, download, get

I've done some research about this and had no conclusive answer.

This question lays some of the path through it: [How can I download only part of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753607/how-can-i-download-only-part-of-a-page)

But then again, I don't want to download only a random part of a page, but one of the first tags, the head.

Is it possible somehow to query the page, and stream it's content to a buffer and stop downloading (discarding the rest) as soon as you find the tag closer `</head>` ?

EDIT:
Adding stuff to the page itself is not possible, since I want to pull the header of websites on my app.

Imagine `http://stackoverflow.com` is entered as the parameter. The whole page is around 240kb, but if I stop downloading the moment I hit `</head>`, it's only 5kb. Allowing me to save around 97% bandwidth for this page.

Comment: problem with this is lets assume the guy wanted to put something in page like current time or username it changes the order of bytes so it is really hard to guess which byte range  has your information and if page is generated by asp.net or something like that oh man

Comment: Yes, providing a byte range is certainly off the plan. That's why I thought that maybe if I could stream the result and stop as soon as I `</head>` is matched, could be a good way of doing it. Now, remains the question: can we stream the page characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is enough for you - Open a URLConnection and read from the input stream

```
    public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                if(inputLine.contains("</head>")) break;
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        }

    }
```

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) you have the tutorial

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't download the whole page and then stream through the downloaded content? If you are, then this is the right answer indeed!

Comment: Documentation says that Httpurlconnection opens socket and stream is Reading from it. So asnwer is, Yes it should download only part of the site.

Comment: I've tested it by using stackoverflow.com as example and nethogs app to  trace bandwidth usage - and with if codition i've downloaded 27KB without if condition I've downloaded over the 50KB. So conclusion is that documentation doesn't lie :)

Comment: One question is, what if the page is compacted and with no lines? Like Google.com page source?