# Python: Download only the HEAD tag of web page

Tags: python, http, python-requests, pycurl

I need to scrape multiple webpages (1000s per hour) as fast as possible, I only need to get the metadata from the head section. I don't think using range headers is going to be reliable as the head sections can vary in size greatly.
I came across another java implementation that Opens a URLConnection and read from the input stream, stopping once you find the closing `</head>` tag

See: [Is it possible to download only the HEAD tag of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424698/is-it-possible-to-download-only-the-head-tag-of-a-page)

is this possible in python?
I've been testing with pycurl and the `WRITEFUNCTION` callback

```py
from time import time
import pycurl
import sys
c = pycurl.Curl()
class Body:
    body = ""
    
    def read(self, buf):     
        self.body += str(buf)
        
b = Body()

c.setopt(c.URL, "https://www.oracle.com/")
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, b.read)

t1 = time()
try:
    c.perform()
except pycurl.error:
    pass

print(time() - t1)
print(b.body)
```

but using Wireshark and setting the debugger to stop in the read function. I'm still seeing all the transactions happen on the first pass.

Comment: One way you could do this is to set TCP receive window size very low (look it up). Then read a (small) suitable amount from the socket in a while loop. Once you get all the content you wanted, stop reading from the socket and close it.  The receive window will fill up and and server will stop sending data. Might have to go low level for this to work though, I don't think requests or even urllib supports altering the receive window.

Comment: @Charchit Yeah something along the lines of this should work. I'm trying to figure out how I can change this at the application level in pycurl. libcurl allows SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF to be changed but I cant find whether this is possible or not in pycurl